# how to extend the length of time when fgetcsv function of php is reading csv file?

Tags: php

am having a problem here, i read a csv file using fgetcsv function then loop it, and write it into an xml file...when am using the script in a not so big data, everything works perfectly and writes the xml file....but when i use it in a huge csv, the xml can't finished being written and end up in an unclosed token thing

```
        if (($handle = fopen("C:\\xampp\htdocs\yii\branch\seo_tagsdev.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 10000000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
                $num = count($data);

                // echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";

                $row++;
                for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) 
                {
                    $url = $doc->createElement('url');
                    $root->appendChild($url);

                    $loc = $doc->createElement('loc',htmlentities($data[$c]));
                    $url->appendChild($loc);

                    $lastmod = $doc->createElement('lastmod',date('Y-m-d'));
                    $url->appendChild($lastmod);

                    $freq = $doc->createElement('changefreq','daily');
                    $url->appendChild($freq);

                    $priority = $doc->createElement('priority',0.9);
                    $url->appendChild($priority);
//                  echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";

                }
                 $doc->save("C:\\xampp\htdocs\yii\branch\seo_tagsdev.xml");
            }
```

i even adjusted the length parameter of fgetcsv and yet it doesn't work at all

Comment: How long are your lines?

Comment: You can just omit the length parameter... or set it to `0` if you want.

Comment: are you talking about [set_time_limit()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)

Comment: i also tried setting it to 0, and am still ending at the same error, unlcosed token thing

Comment: what is the **exact** error message

Comment: XML Parsing Error: unclosed token ...when i viewed the xml file that got generated...it's not even in the half way reading the csv file..that's why it got broken

Comment: sure the csv file is valid?

Comment: It look like your script abruptly terminated while sending the output ... are you using `ob_start()` anywhere?

Comment: am not using any ob_start() ...and how can i know if the csv file is valid? ....

Comment: the csv file is i think valid, because, there's only 1 line in each row

Comment: It's advisable to start with `error_reporting(-1)` and `ini_set('display_errors', 'On')` ... any errors should be noticed easily.